# Why adding CSS gradient disables background color style?

Tags: css, html, gradient, background-color

I've created horizontal menue with automaticaly highlighted current item.

```
#nav li a 
{
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #003254; 
}
```

by using this trick:

```
<body id="home">
```

and this CSS trick

```
body#home ul#nav .menu-home, 
....
body#contact ul#nav .menu-contact {  background-color:  #EB9152;   }
```

This worked until I decided to add gradient to each point. Gradient is added to this fragment:

```
#nav li a 
{
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #003254; 

  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(241,241,241,1) 0%, rgba(246,246,246,1) 47%, rgba(215,215,215,1) 100%);
  ..
```

After that, current menue selection does not work any more - the current item does not change its presentation it all. Any idea why?

Comment: You're not closing your `}` on your style block. Do those 2 dots represent that, or is that in your file too?

Comment: Sorry, I've cut the code - too many different gradients

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused about your "current page highlighting trick", but it looks like you're simply overwriting your background color with the gradient. Have you tried using:

```
background-color:  #EB9152!important;
```

Comment: Frankly, I copy-pasted that trick from internet and have no complete understanding how it works. !important did not worked. ;(

Comment: can you provide a link to what you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

By trial and error, it worked after I moved gradient from (nav li a) block to (nav) block - here the full code:

```
#nav
{
  float: right;   
  margin: 0 0 3em 0;
  padding: 0 0;
  list-style: none;

      background-color: rgba(225, 225, 225, .0);
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(241,241,241,1) 0%, rgba(246,246,246,1) 47%, rgba(215,215,215,1) 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(241,241,241,1)), color-stop(47%, rgba(246,246,246,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(215,215,215,1)));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(241,241,241,1) 0%, rgba(246,246,246,1) 47%, rgba(215,215,215,1) 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(241,241,241,1) 0%, rgba(246,246,246,1) 47%, rgba(215,215,215,1) 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(241,241,241,1) 0%, rgba(246,246,246,1) 47%, rgba(215,215,215,1) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(241,241,241,1) 0%, rgba(246,246,246,1) 47%, rgba(215,215,215,1) 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f1f1f1', endColorstr='#d7d7d7', GradientType=0 );

}
#nav li { float: left;   }
#nav li a 
{
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #003254; 

    border-right-style:solid;
    border-right-color:#fff;
    border-right-width: 1px;
}
```